# how to remove a character in database " mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php   
 if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
    {
    $t = "UPDATE golf_details SET description = REPLACE(description , '"', '')";
    mysql_query($t);
    }
    echo "hwllo";
?>
```

How to replace " to blank or it can be how to remove " from form on submit click.??

Comment: Why has no one given the "Do not use mysql_*" lecture? :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the SQL to escape double quotes.

```
$t = "UPDATE golf_details SET description = REPLACE(description , '\"', '')";
mysql_query($t);
```

You were using double quotes in the `SET`, ofcourse, it was breaking the PHP string.

Answer (score 5):

PHP `str_replace()`

```
$desc=str_replace('"','',$desc);
echo $desc;
```

then in your statement

```
UPDATE XX SET description=$desc
```